# php - get different dates in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this while loop:

```
<?php 

          $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xeon_stats_clicks WHERE user='".$userdata['username']."' AND typ='4' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 8") or die(mysql_error());   
          while($clickData=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)): 

              $r=mysql_query("SELECT sum(value) FROM `xeon_stats_clicks` WHERE user='".$userdata['username']."' AND typ='3' AND data='".date("Y/m/d")."' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 8");
             echo mysql_result($r, 0);



         endwhile;

          ?>
```

This will just give me the sum of the value row for today only. How can I do so I get the data from the last 7 days?

Comment: use between clause.. today's date and 7 days before date

Comment: `>= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK `, if you bothered to use actual DATE  / DATETIME / TIMESTAMP columns.

Comment: Could you please make an example?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to specify the certain date for it will give you on this specific date, another comment suggested the use of 'between' but I like the use of '>' only in this case,
for example:

> SELECT sum(value) FROM `xeon_stats_clicks` WHERE
>   user=.$userdata['username'] AND type='3' AND date > CURDATE() -
>   INTERVAL 1 WEEK ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 8"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( value ), `data` 
FROM table 
WHERE ( `data` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
GROUP BY `data`
```

for example.

try another where statement:

```
DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) = 7
```

and show your where statement

Comment: swap the two BETWEEN arguments? i dont understand it.

Comment: like this `select "2013/09/21" BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE()`